# How do I update an Android project from a Jenkins job?

Tags: android, jenkins

I am setting up Jenkins to clone my git project, update the project, then build using ant. If I perform an ls in the job after cloning the repo, I see my project.properties file present (containing target).

To update the project (and therefore generate the build.xml file) I issue the following command:

```
android update project -p ./
```

However, I get the following console output:

```
Error: The project either has no target set or the target is invalid.
```

Does anyone know how to update an android project from Jenkins and avoid this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you've eliminated the first part of the error (i.e. the project *does* have a target set), but not the second part.

The message "`target is invalid`" means that you don't have the target platform installed in the Android SDK that Jenkins is using.

e.g. if your target is `android-17`, then you need to install the Android 4.2 platform (for example via the command `android update sdk -u -t android-17`).

As an aside, you can automate both the relevant calls to `android update -p` and the installation of required target platforms using the [Android Emulator Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Android+Emulator+Plugin) for Jenkins.